# How to get multiple buttons on the same line within a table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I am working on creating an online shop from scratch in IntelliJ. Right now I am having difficulty displaying the buttons to increase/decrease quantity on the same line as the quantity.

I have attempted some suggested solutions from this website which I've seen regarding CSS and classes but to no avail. I've also tried using a mixture of ids and classes.

Below is the HTML:

```
<td><div id="outer">
    <div class="inner"><button type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.jpg" alt="minus" height="10px" width="10px"/></button></div>
    <div class="inner"><input type="text" name="name" value="1"></div>
    <div class="inner"><button type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.jpg" alt="plus" height="20px" width="20px"/></button></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Below is the corresponding part of the CSS which I tried:

```
#outer
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Currently each component is still displaying on top of eachother rather than next to eachother

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#outer {
    display: flex;
    width: 250px;
}
</style>
```

You can use FlexBox on the parent container which will move all the children (in default setting) in flex-direction: row; so essentially 1st element, 2nd element, 3rd element.

Furthermore, I set the width to 250px to keep the container as small as possible. You can use `border: 1px solid red` to see the size of the container. If you want the container to take the full length use `justify-content: center` and get rid of the width selector.

Display: flex isnt a new technology either so there is no reason not to learn it and use it. The latest and greatest positioning element is CSS Grids.

Comment: @UlysseBN I didnt see him posting anywhere that he needs it to be compatible with IE. Not using flexbox because 2% of the world uses an ultra outdated browser seems a little silly.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately, appreciate the suggestion though

Comment: @sh.learner it works for me, try removing the `<style>` tags they're intended for inline CSS on your HTML file. If it's just going in your CSS file you don't need those tags. Perhaps that's the issue you're facing currently?

Comment: I replaced the #outer in my CSS with this ( style tags removed) but the components were still on top of each other. I'm using google chrome btw so perhaps this is the reason

Comment: @sh.learner odd, perhaps it's because I dont have access to the images your using for your buttons so I'm getting a default no img icon. Trying also adding padding: 15px or so so there is more available room in the container. 

```#outer {
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: flex;
 width: 250px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

Also, I am using Chrome too. It's the best browser to use because everything is compatible with it.

Comment: @kevin even if he didn't express it, my message was more of a warning. Unfortunately sometimes you have to deal with the 2%

Comment: @UlysseBN I guess, but just posting that "This is not compatible" with a 6 year old browser that Microsoft is currently two complete generations away from now is pointless. Yes, I suppose it's always good to check for compatibility, but sweating IE compatibility is extremely unnecessary especially given the circumstances of this question.

Comment: @kevin hi, I retried your method and it worked this time. Think there was a conflict with my css initially. I'm sticking with this method and will attempt to upvote(not sure if it will register as my score is quite low)

Comment: @sh.learner awesome! Hopefully it goes through. Watch some tutorials on Flexbox if you have time, it's a really powerful tool that makes your page so much more responsive. The next evolution after Flexbox is CSS Grids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<table id="outer">
    <tr class="inner">
        <td>
            <button type="button" name="button"><img src="minus.jpg" alt="minus" height="10px" width="10px"/></button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" name="button"><img src="plus.jpg" alt="plus" height="20px" width="20px"/></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Initially I wanted the components in one cell rather than different cells however this worked well for me as an alternative. Thanks